# Why doesn't library source file include its header

Tags: c++, opencv

I am currently trying to explore about OpenCV.

When I looked for Mat class, i can see that it is defined in `mat.hpp`, which is located in an include folder. However, when I attempted to search for its corresponding `mat.cpp`, I found that the class definition is actually located in `matrix.cpp`. I suppose the difference in file name is not a problem, as long as it includes `mat.hpp`. However, the header `mat.hpp` wasn't included either. I know the compiler would probably still able to compile, but as far as I know, this is a bad programming practice.

So, my question is, is it true that it is a bad practice not to include the header file in the source file? Is there any reason why it should not be included?

I understand that I do not need to explore too much about the detailed implementation of the library, but this question is just out of curiosity.

Here is the `#include` part of the `matrix.cpp`

```
#include "precomp.hpp"
#include "opencl_kernels_core.hpp"
#include "bufferpool.impl.hpp"
```

And here is the `#include` part of the `mat.hpp`

```
#include "opencv2/core/matx.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/types.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/bufferpool.hpp"
```

Comment: At the beginning you are saying "`Mat` class is *defined* in `mat.hpp`". Immediately after that you are saying "I found that the class *definition* is actually located in `matrix.cpp`". This seems to be self-contradictory. Again, where is the class *definition* located?

Comment: Sorry, i used the wrong word here. Mat is <i>declared</i> in mat.hpp, not defined

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: That's how the project evolved.

The long answer is: OpenCV did (and still does) declare many of its functions and classes in `core.hpp` while the many `.cpp` files hold the implementations. In this case, matrix-specific functions (and implementations for `Mat`) would be in `matrix.cpp` and definitions for classes, like `Mat`, would be in `core.hpp`.

As the project grew, things seem to get split up (probably just to be easier to manage). You can see in [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/715fa3303ea56483447992204ece63401b98ab2c) commit, the class `Mat` was moved out of `core.hpp` into its own `mat.hpp` (named as such probably to match the class name). The source file `matrix.cpp` does include `mat.hpp`, though indirectly (through `precomp.hpp` and `core.hpp`).

I don't think this confusion is intentional, just incidental. Is this bad practice? Some would say so, but thats up to you to decide.

*Disclaimer: I have not worked on the OpenCV source, but did use it extensively for a time.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why do they have indirect inclusion here? Why not just include "mat.hpp" directly?

Answer (score 3):

In C++, when you define a class in a header file and then define class members (methods and such) in a `.cpp` file, the class definition is supposed to be visible in that `.cpp` file. This is usually achieved by including the header file with the class definition into the `.cpp` file(s) that defines the members.

In OpenCV `mat.hpp` is included into `matrix.cpp` indirectly. `matrix.cpp` includes `precomp.hpp`, which in turn includes `core.hpp`, which in turn includes `mat.hpp`.

So, `mat.hpp` is actually included into `matrix.cpp`. Nothing unusual here.

P.S. File names play no role whatsoever. There's nothing unusual in `mat.hpp` being named "differently" from `matrix.cpp`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why do they have indirect inclusion here? Why not just include "mat.hpp" directly?

Comment: @Le Hoang Long: The name of the intermediate header - `precomp.hpp` - clearly suggest that they do it for the purposes of header precompilation. Apparently all widely and frequently used headers are supposed to be included through `precomp.hpp`, which is pre-compiled.

Comment: Ah, i see. So that it will be easier to manage header files since they will only need to include precomp.hpp now